# C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile\desktop is unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, sql-server-2014

We are trying to set up Always On Availability Groups for SQL Server 2014 and we began with creating a cluster between two SQL Servers. Everything went fine until validating cluster creation and clicking on "Finish" button which suddenly led to this message : "C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile\desktop is unavailable".

After some investigation, we found that our IT department has moved personal folders to D:\Users and not C:\Users as it should be by default (we also checked with other servers and it's the case).

We compared also the %USERPROFILE% variable and these are the values :

- Other safe servers : **D:\Users\CurrentUserName**
- Our faulty SQL Servers : **C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile**

Does anyone have an idea about what could have happened through cluster creation process that could have changed the %USERPROFILE% value ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *Other safe servers*. Also, how do you know that the `%USERPROFILE%` variable was changed by the cluster creation process?

Comment: By 'Other safe serverd' I mean the other SharePoint servers that has no problem with personal folder location, because, at servers creation, both SharePoint ans sql servers have the same config.

Comment: I knew that the %USERPROFILE% variable was changed after cluster creation because the issue appeared just after clicking on the 'Finish' button of the creation wizard. Before that everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

**In order to restore the default path try to do following before clicking the 'Finish' button:**

- Click the **Start** button.
- Click Computer.
- Navigate to D:\Users\
- Open the folder with your username.
- Right click on the Desktop folder and click Properties.
- Click the ‘Location’ tab and click the ‘Restore Default’ button.

**If you are unable to do that:**

- Click the Start button.
- Type **regedit** and press Enter to open the Registry Editor.
- Navigate to the following registry key: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell\Folders**
- On the right, double click the Desktop key.
- Make sure the Desktop value is set to: **“%USERPROFILE%\Desktop”** or    **“D:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop”**
- Click OK and close the Registry Editor.